# Create Azure container from an existing VPN

Tags: azure, containers, vpn, azure-aks, azure-container-instances

We have a huge roadblock of using Azure containers on ACI because we couldn't connect them back on on-premise from an existing VPN.
When following the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet#preview-limitations), we try to create the new container to an existing VPN that connect to on-promise, it never works. Here are our command.

```
PS D:\Azure> az container create --resource-group DEV_MitchellVPN2 --name garytestvnet4 --image centos --vnet DEV_MitchellVPN2_VNET --subnet Subnet1 --ports 80 443 --ip-address Private

Image "centos" has no long running process. The "--command-line" argument must be used to start a long running process inside the container for
the container group to stay running. Ex: "tail -f /dev/null" For more imformation visit https://aka.ms/aci/troubleshoot
Resource /subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/DEV_MitchellVPN2/providers/Microsoft.Network/routeTables/DEV_MitchellVPN2_RouteTable cannot be created in or updated to use the subnet /subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/DEV_MitchellVPN2/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/DEV_MitchellVPN2_VNET/subnets/Subnet1 since it has delegation(s) [Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups: /subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/DEV_MitchellVPN2/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/DEV_MitchellVPN2_VNET/subnets/Subnet1/delegations/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups] to external services.
```

Comment: Cross posted Here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/39330 and Here:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/313b22cf-b24a-4b93-b52d-83448d4be5c8/create-aci-container-from-an-existing-vpn-that-connected-to-onpremise?forum=AzureContainerServices&prof=required

Comment: You can take a try currently, it seems the error disappears.